# Is There a Way to Enter Text into a Modern Page Table (in Text) Whole Rows at a Time, Instead of Pasting Cell by Cell

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages, table

I think my question title says it all: When I make a table on a Modern page, it seems like the only way to enter content into that table is cell by cell. I've tried pasting in and entire row (just text in this case) with tabs between each cell, but everything just gets pasted into the one cell I have my entry point in. This because very cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the only way to enter content into that table is cell by cell.

Because the [table in a Text web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-text-and-tables-to-your-page-with-the-text-web-part-729c0aa1-bc0d-41e3-9cde-c60533f2c801) is purely **text** contents, so it does not have the **AutoFill** feature similar to Excel workbook.

You might consider creating a workbook and using [File Viewer web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-file-viewer-web-part-e53a9602-e7b3-4fff-9126-de2f18d1900c) if it suits your need.